# Flux with Alt - Simultaneous dispatches means wrong design pattern?

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, components, flux

I build an app with pure React. Its primary page shows multiple movies (user added). Users can vote and comment on every movie listed. I have a `MovieCard` component, which is responsible for a single movie. Then in `Home` I render an array of `MovieCard` components. Next I decided to implement a call to foreign movie database API, to get relevant movie information. It worked fine. Then I decided to refactor it in Flux pattern, using Alt and following the guidelines of [this](http://sahatyalkabov.com/create-a-character-voting-app-using-react-nodejs-mongodb-and-socketio/) tutorial. Everything worked well, until I got the the `MovieCard`. In there, inside `componentDidMount` I call the action, which sends `ajax` and retrieves a poster url. And I got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

First, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353108/cannot-dispatch-in-the-middle-of-a-dispatch) topic. The author of the answer claimed that having each component handles its actions is bad design pattern and is what cause the error. His solution would be to handle ALL actions and stores from the top-most component (App) and pass down as props. My thoughts:

- I don't like it, because it means passing down a LOT of `data` and `callbacks` and my App.js is going to be overly long and ugly and clouded. Lastly I don't know how this is the "React way", where each component is standalone and can work on it's own, out of App context.
- I don't see how it fixes the problem. I want my `MovieCard` to fire action to get `data` inside `componentDidMount`. So even if `App` is handling the actions, when multiple movies are shown, then multiple actions will be fired, again.

Then I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581587/flux-dispatch-dispatch-cannot-dispatch-in-the-middle-of-a-dispatch) topic. I don't think I am using actions wrong. Here is my action:

```
getMoviePoster(movieName) {
    TMDB.getMoviePoster(movieName)
        .then(data => this.getMoviePosterSuccess(data))
        .catch(err => this.getMoviePosterFail(err));

    return true;
}
```

I followed the pattern, showed in the guide I linked above. There were no errors there.

I read through some other topics, there was something about `waitFor` token, but I couldn't make much of it. Can anyone please shed some light on the issue, because I am in sort of a hurry. I need it done by Tuesday, and I may have a major refactoring on my hands now... I really don't understand what is the problem here. I know Flux is unidirectional, but I thought that's for one component. I'm not guru here, but I can't really see unidirectional flow for the entire application (even this small). I don't see what's the problem of having multiple instances of the same component doing stuff simultaneously.

**EDIT**: I read again through Alt [docs](http://alt.js.org/docs/) and getting started [guide](http://alt.js.org/guide/) I don't see anything against multiple dispatches. I read about `AltContainer`, but i'd like to keep my app and structure simple at the moment. In my action constructor I use `this.generateActions`; in store - `this.bindActions(MovieCardActions)`, which works very well. Except when I have multiple components mounted at the same time. I still can't get the problem.

Comment: I don't understand. Are there no people developing with Alt, or is my question so stupid that it doesn't deserve an answer?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I understand that the question was written from a position of not knowing what specific question to ask (“Can anyone please shed some light on the issue […]”), but StackExchange is not a good forum for such broad calls for help. That is likely the explanation for why this question didn't receive an answer. You'll need to refine this to [ask a question that in principle has *one correct answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That may entail narrowing the scope of what you're asking.

Comment: TLDR: why am I getting this error, when I let the moviecard component to handle it its data request on its own?

Comment: that looks like a good start for you to re-write the question to narrow the scope.