# How to fire actions simultaneously from multiple components with Alt (Flux)

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, flux, reactjs-flux

I am using Alt library for Flux architecture implementation. I have a component, which displays information about movie. Now I am stuck in a situation where I need to render array of such components under my home page. The problem is that each of these components calls `ajax request` inside `componentDidMount`. So when I have more then one - I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Dispatch.dispatch(...): Cannot dispatch in the middle of a dispatch.
```

I wrote a longer post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720979/flux-with-alt-simultaneous-dispatches-means-wrong-design-pattern), this is a more succinct version. I simply cannot understand the nature of the problem.

**EDIT**: Clarifying with an image. Basically I get the poster for the first component and on the second it throws an error and stops working:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of researching and some help, I got my problem solved.

The simple answer is: You cannot. This is considered not only bad practice, but **Flux** anti-pattern, an as such is restricted by the standard Facebook dispatcher (which is what **Alt** uses). The correct way would be to handle **actions** and **stores** from the **top-most** component. You could also use custom dispatcher, but I guess it's not restricted for no reason.

In my case that was the HomePage component and what I did was to fire single **action**, which got all movie posters and then passed that information down with **props**.

As far as I understand the best practice would be to have a **container component** at the **top-most**, which is only responsible for **actions** and **stores**. Then inside the container - a **view component** (one or more), which are responsible for rendering the UI and data. I find [this](http://blog.mgechev.com/2015/05/15/flux-in-depth-overview-components/) article well informative.